# C# Escape illegal xml characters from node text only

Tags: c#, xml

I am working with an API and for some crazy reason the XML being returned has & characters that are not correctly escaped. This has left me in an annoying position. I get an exception when i try to use an `XMLDocument` to parse the xml string.

I can use replace to get rid of the characters, but this could lead to issues.

```
xml = xml.Replace("&amp;", "&").Replace("&", "&amp;");
```

The problem with this is that there may end up being some escaped values. A node like this will cause the line of code above to get screwed up.

```
<node>Something & something &lt; annoying</node>
```

If i replace the & characters with amp; it will break lt;. I cant use the same approach for lt; as i did for the amp as it will mean that it will convert all of the <> brackets that i still need to get escaped.

Here is a node that is giving trouble.

```
<CompanyName>Fire & Ice</CompanyName>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the erroneous XML?

Comment: I had already given an example in the <node> example. This is xml that i need to be able to handle. I have provided another example of the issue that i face at the moment

Comment: What about Replace(" & ", "&amp;")?

Comment: Please ask the creator of that XML to fix it. That's the only way of getting it right.

Comment: Either you have to call XMLTidy or something. Or write your own tokenized separator and replace each token that is just & character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a similar regex to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654537/fixing-unescaped-xml-entities-in-java-with-regex).  This essentialy matches all unescaped ampersands (i.e. it will match `&`, but not `&something;`).

```
var xml = @"<node>Something & something &lt; annoying</node>";

var result = Regex.Replace(xml, @"&(?!\w*;)", "&amp;");

// output: <node>Something &amp; something &lt; annoying</node>
```

Comment: That does not work in all scenarios. Consider this &hello will not be replaced with &amp;hello

Comment: @fahadash yes, it will. The negative lookahead requires a word and a semi-colon, and `&hello` doesn't match that.

Comment: @fahadash I'm not sure what you're saying.  It's the *negative* lookahead that doesn't get matched, so it *will* be replaced. `&hello` will be replaced by `&amp;hello`.  The former is invalid, so surely this is what is expected?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say `&hello;` (with the semi-colon), we do want it to be `&amp;hello;` although your solution is very close and might suffice for the OP. +1

Comment: @fahadash `&hello;` is a valid XML entity reference can can be handled as such by a DTD or tooling. I'm not sure you could say for sure you'd want it to be replaced.

Comment: DTD does not specify what chars are valid and what aren't. XML specification does, and & should always be represented in form of `&amp;` regardless of whether or not the modern parsers can handle it. Source: Chapter 1 of https://amzn.com/1118162137

Comment: @fahadash I'm not talking about *characters*, I'm talking about *entity references*.  `&hello;` is a valid *entity reference*, and a DTD can specify what that maps to.  See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd_entities.asp) for some examples.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to you XElement.XElement is useful object.XElement.Value will return string that you want.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
XElement y = new XElement("CompanyNames",
                new XElement("CompanyName", "Fire & Ice")
                );
foreach (var item in y.Elements("CompanyName"))
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

Output will be "Fire & Ice"

Comment: If the XML is invalid, it won't be able to parse it. I don't see how this helps.

Comment: XElement can parse invalid XML?

Comment: @CharlesMager "An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 1, position 18." when using `XDocument.Parse` on the `<node>` example above.

Comment: Please add some code sample or links to examples that correspond to the original question.